# how to convert a number into timestamp in oracle/sql

Tags: sql, oracle

how to convert a number into timestamp(6) in  oracle?
ie convert 20131108 to 08-NOV-13 12.00.00.000000 AM or any format in timestamp(6).
Thanks!

Comment: Why did you tag this as MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You convert your number to a string with to_char. Then you convert that string to timestamp with to_timestamp. Time will automatically be midnight.

```
select to_timestamp( to_char(20131108) ,'yyyymmdd') from dual
```

Comment: @user2846737 If you like the answer you can mark it as resolved.

Comment: works when all you have to deal with is the date. Looking for the time of day by itself, is a bit more challenging to this Oracle newbie